# Плавность курсора

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такой код:

```js
$('.box').mousemove(function(event) {
  $('.cursor').css({
    'top' : event.pageY + 'px',
    'left' : event.pageX + 'px',
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor:default;
}

.cursor-ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
}


.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  
<div class="box"> </div>

<div class="cursor" >   
  <svg class="cursor-ico" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 83.7 60">
    <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="245" d="M42.1,1.5C58,1.5,70.8,14.3,70.8,30S58,58.5,42.1,58.5c-15.8,0-28.7-12.8-28.7-28.5S26.3,1.5,42.1,1.5z"></path>      
  </svg>
</div>
```

Блок, внутри которого должен начинать срабатывать "кастомный курсор" в виде svg круга. Но проблема в том, что движение этого круга происходит как с заеданием.

И таким движение становится, только, если задавать движение внутри определенного блока - `$('.box').mousemove`.

Если же задать `$(window).mousemove` то все прекрасно работает:

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  $('.cursor').css({
    'top' : event.pageY + 'px',
    'left' : event.pageX + 'px',
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor:default;
}

.cursor-ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
}


.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  
<div class="box"> </div>


<div class="cursor" >   
  <svg class="cursor-ico" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 83.7 60">
    <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="245" d="M42.1,1.5C58,1.5,70.8,14.3,70.8,30S58,58.5,42.1,58.5c-15.8,0-28.7-12.8-28.7-28.5S26.3,1.5,42.1,1.5z"></path>      
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** как задать плавное движение блока "курсора" за мышью внутри определенного блока?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например

UPD. Исправил для корректной работы по оси Y

```js
$('.box, .cursor').mousemove(function(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX,
    posY = event.pageY - 500;

  if (posX > $(".box").width() || posY > 0) {
  } else {
    $('.cursor').css({
      // 'top' : event.pageY + 'px',
      // 'left' : event.pageX + 'px',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      '-o-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      'transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
    });
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: default;
}

.cursor-ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<div class="box"> </div>

<div class="cursor">
  <svg class="cursor-ico" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 83.7 60">
    <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="245" d="M42.1,1.5C58,1.5,70.8,14.3,70.8,30S58,58.5,42.1,58.5c-15.8,0-28.7-12.8-28.7-28.5S26.3,1.5,42.1,1.5z"></path>      
  </svg>
</div>
```