# Плавность курсора в нескольких блоках

Tags: html, jquery, css

Этот вопрос вытекает из [предыдущего вопроса о курсоре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787720/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

К примеру есть несколько блоков внутри которых должен срабатывать курсор (плавно срабатывать). Для плавность из прошлого вопроса следует такая запись - `$('.box, .cursor').mousemove`:

```js
$('.box, .cursor').mousemove(function(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX,
    posY = event.pageY - 500;

  if (posX > $(".box").width() || posY > 0) {
  } else {
    $('.cursor').css({
      // 'top' : event.pageY + 'px',
      // 'left' : event.pageX + 'px',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      '-o-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
      'transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
    });
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: default;
}

.cursor-ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
</div>

<div class="cursor" >   
  <svg class="cursor-ico" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 83.7 60">
    <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="245" d="M42.1,1.5C58,1.5,70.8,14.3,70.8,30S58,58.5,42.1,58.5c-15.8,0-28.7-12.8-28.7-28.5S26.3,1.5,42.1,1.5z"></path>
    <path stroke="none" d="M4.5,32.6v-7.9l-4.5,4L4.5,32.6z M79.2,24.7v7.9l4.5-4L79.2,24.7z" class="cursor-arrow"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли и как задать плавное движение "курсора" - svg круга внутри каждого и определенного блока (`.box`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var activeBox,
    bxQuant = $(".box").length;

  function boxPos() {
    var bxCount = 0
    $(".box").each(function() {
      window["bx_" + bxCount + "_posX"] = $(this).offset().left;
      window["bx_" + bxCount + "_posY"] = $(this).offset().top;

      window["bx_" + bxCount + "_sizeX"] = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
      window["bx_" + bxCount + "_sizeY"] = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
      bxCount++;
    });
  };

  boxPos();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    boxPos();
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var posX = event.pageX,
      posY = event.pageY;


    for (var i = 0; i < bxQuant; i++) {
      if ((posX > window["bx_" + i + "_posX"] && posY > window["bx_" + i + "_posY"] && posX < window["bx_" + i + "_sizeX"] && posY < window["bx_" + i + "_sizeY"])) {
        $('.cursor').css({
          // 'top' : event.pageY + 'px',
          // 'left' : event.pageX + 'px',
          '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
          '-ms-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
          '-o-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
          'transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px) translateZ(0px)',
        });
      };
    };
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: default;
}

.cursor-ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cursor">
  <svg class="cursor-ico" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 83.7 60">
   <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="245" d="M42.1,1.5C58,1.5,70.8,14.3,70.8,30S58,58.5,42.1,58.5c-15.8,0-28.7-12.8-28.7-28.5S26.3,1.5,42.1,1.5z"></path>
   <path stroke="none" d="M4.5,32.6v-7.9l-4.5,4L4.5,32.6z M79.2,24.7v7.9l4.5-4L79.2,24.7z" class="cursor-arrow"></path>
 </svg>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Увеличил на весь экран, не работает....

Comment: @Air исправил..

Comment: Уже оценил)))))